# I am getting nullpointer exception on Textview's settext(charSeq) method?

Tags: android, textview

I have given my code below.I am just want to create a custom dialog in android.whenever i click on button it will show a custom dialog box.i have created a xml "alert.xml".after click on button i will show the content from string.xml

```
  public class TriangleActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
            /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            private Button bt;
            private Dialog dialog;
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                bt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                bt.setOnClickListener(this);
                //Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
                dialog = new Dialog(TriangleActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert);
                dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
                TextView t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

                t.setText(getString(R.string.h));

            }
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                dialog.show();
            }
        }
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

alert.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" >
        <TextView 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/tv1" >           

        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>I am getting 
<resources>

    <string name="hello">Hello World, TriangleActivity!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Triangle</string>
     <string name="h">The Royal Society of Chemistry’s interactive periodic table which </string>

</resources>
```

Comment: It apparently isn't finding the control in the look up (line before error).  You should always do null checks on items that can be null btw.  It's good practice to follow.   Also - is it finding the button okay?

Comment: Try to use `this.getResources().getString((R.string.h)` instead of `getString(R.string.h)`

Answer (score 4):

use this to find the textview:

```
TextView t=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView t=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

This is ur solution dude

Answer (score 2):

Modify your textView initialization.. because its unable to find the dialog view..so do this--

```
TextView t=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 1):

if t.setText(getString(R.string.h)); is throwing exception NullPointerException, it means, either t or getString(R.string.h) is null. 
t might be null, if main.xml does not have a TextView with id, @+id/tv1.

Answer (score 0):

TextView text = (TextView)findviewByid(R.id.text1);